# if variable increases or decreases, how do i check?

Tags: jquery

In Jquery, I am trying to check if my variables from the input increase or decrease. Below is what I have tried. How do i write if value increases or decreases of a variable?  I tried `var amt = $("#current").val();  if (amt > amt){  //do this};`

Comment: You are comparing two same variables to eachother?

Comment: You'd have to store the previous value of the variable somewhere. That somewhere depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Obviously can't do that so you need to explain more about what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store current input value as a variable, and then compare it to the new input value.

```
(function(){
 var $input = $('#current'),
     value  = $('#current').val();


 $input.on('change', function(){
     var newValue = $(this).val();

     if(newValue > value) doSomething();
 });


})();
```